# Assert that one run is significantly faster than one other

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, time

I need to make a functionnal test that assert that one run is **significantly** faster than one other.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
def test_run5(self):
    cmd_line = ["python", self.__right_def_file_only_files]
    start = time.clock()
    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
        ClassName().run(cmd_line)
    end = time.clock()
    runtime1 = end - start

    start = time.clock()
    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
        ClassName().run(cmd_line)
    end = time.clock()
    runtime2 = end - start

    self.assertTrue(runtime2 < runtime1 * 1.4)
```

It works but I don't like this way because the 1.4 factor has been chosen experimentaly with my *specific* example of execution.

How would you test that the second execution is **always** faster than the first?

**EDIT**

I didn't think that it would be necessary to explain it but in the context of my program, it is not up to me to say that a factor is significant for an unknown execution.

The whole program is a kind of `Make` and it is the *pipeline definition file* that will define what is the "significant difference of speed", not me:

- If the definition file contains a lot of rules that are very fast, the difference of execution time between two consecutive execution will be very small, let's say 5% faster but still significant
- Else if the definition file contains few rules but very long ones, the difference will be big, let's say 90% faster so a difference of 5% would not be significant at all.

Comment: Why the `1.4`? Just using `runtime2 < runtime1` also checks if `runtime2` was faster!

Comment: You could also [`self.assertGreater`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertGreater)

Comment: Because `runtime2 < runtime1` doesn't answer to the "significantly" point. The two execution could have approximatively the same run-time with `runtime2` effectively lower than `runtime1`. Thanks for the `assertGreater`, i'll use it.

Comment: It is up to you to define how much is *significant*. We cannot do that for you.

Comment: I was thinking that, maybe, there could be a formula which would find dynamically the good factor for `runtime1`.

Comment: What would *"the good factor"* even mean? Only **you** can decide what counts as *"significantly"* for your purposes. Just use the lowest bound you would consider to be significant.

Comment: I edited my post to make it more clear.Writing this edit, I realize that I should have given the "definition file size" parameter to allow you to help me.

So, given the definition file size and the execution time of the first execution, I can calculate the average rule execution time, say `A`. The higher is the `A`, the higher should be the factor between `runtime1` and `runtime2` with a limit at 1. I thought `log(1+x)` but it doesn't grew fast enougth in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out an equation named [`Michaelis-Menten kinetics`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics) which fit with my needs. Here is the function which should do the trick

```
def get_best_factor(full_exec_time, rule_count, maximum_ratio=1):
    average_rule_time = full_exec_time / rule_count
    return 1 + (maximum_ratio * average_rule_time / (1.5 + average_rule_time))
```

- `full_exec_time` parameter is `runtime1` which is the maximum execution time for a given pipeline definition file.
- `rule_count` is the number of rules in the given pipeline definition file.
- `maximum_ratio` means that the second execution will be, at max, 100% faster than the first (impossible, in practice)

The variable parameter of the `Michaelis-Menten kinetics` equation, is the average rule execution time. And I have arbitrarily chosen `1.5 seconds` as the average rule execution time at which the execution time should be `maximum_ratio / 2` faster. It is the actual parameter that depends on your use of this equation.